# How to sort name and index in the pandas dataframe, and exporting each name to the excel template in specific position

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

Now I am having a pandas dataframe as below:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| name|index|val_a|val_b|val_c|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    A|    1|  0.1|  0.2|  0.3|
|    B|    1|  1.1|  3.2|  2.3|
|    A|    2|  1.5|  9.9|  4.5|
|    A|    3|  7.7|  7.6|  4.9|
|    B|    2|  3.9|  3.4|  2.3|
|    C|    1|  5.8|  2.4|  1.3|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

And after I sort by name and index, it looks like the below:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| name|index|val_a|val_b|val_c|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    A|    1|  0.1|  0.2|  0.3|
|    A|    2|  1.5|  9.9|  4.5|
|    A|    3|  7.7|  7.6|  4.9|
|    B|    1|  1.1|  3.2|  2.3|
|    B|    2|  3.9|  3.4|  2.3|
|    C|    1|  5.8|  2.4|  1.3|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

And I also have an Excel template, and would like to export from specific position (starting from column c).

How could I export? For example, all 3 rows of name A export to the excel worksheet from column c and the same with other items respectively.

---

Below is the template, and there're 5 worksheets in the excel:
[image: template.xlsx]

Comment: Can you show your expected output ?

Comment: I have a template for exporting (template.xls). If I export name A items to the template, then save as output_A.xls. Same as B and C, open the template again and exporting B to the tempalte and save as output_B.xls

Comment: Do you need to conserve the existing styles/formatting of the template ?

Comment: No need, the template just an Excel document and I just want to export each name sets to the specific position only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try this :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

for name, group in df.groupby("name"):
    wb = load_workbook("template.xlsx")
    ws = wb["Vectors"]
    for row in group.to_numpy().tolist():
        row = [None]*2 + row
        ws.append(row)
    wb.save(f"Output_{name}.xlsx")
    wb.close()
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: thank you, better than my previous method exporting row by row.

Comment: but one more question, why I cannot successfully open the template file, my template file path is '/xxx/xxx/xxx/template.xlsx', but the result give me an empty worksheet with the data.

Comment: What's the sheet name of the template ? And how look like your template ? Can you show a screenshot ?

Comment: template_file = f"/synfs/{JobId}/output/template/template.xlsx"

Then i use template_file to replace "template.xlsx" in your code.

Comment: But what's the sheet name of your template.xslx ? I would be simple if you show a small screenshot.

Comment: Hi @Timeless, I put the screencap in the question.

Comment: Besides the sheet name, I meant a screenshot of the sheet itself. Anyways, I updated my answer. Can you check test again ?

Comment: Tried serveral times but at least 'vectors' sheet can be exported, but how if we want to export the entire workbook?

Comment: That's because you failed to describe your needs and since you're not OK for making a screenshot of the whole tempalte.xlsx, you need to describe clearly how look like this template (number of sheets, sheet names, ..) and how should look like the new Excel files.

Comment: Hi @Timeless, sorry for unclear needs, I thought it was extracting the dataframe and paste into specific place into the excel. I had posted the screenshot of the excel and there are 5 sheets. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, can you check the update please ?

Comment: Hi @Timeless, the excel had been successfullly exported, but the dataframe cannot export to the excel.

Comment: @jasondes, I made a small fix and this time should be good ;)